# Java .equals bug for a string

Tags: java, string

I'm going to code a program where should be test two strings to equality. The console puts two equal words out but the if condition says nope.
That's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("nextState(" + i + "): " + states.get(i).getName());
    System.out.println("rule: " + ruleSplitted.get(0));
    if(states.get(i).getName().equals(ruleSplitted.get(0))){
          actState = states.get(i);
    }
}
```

That says the console:

```
nextState(0): state1
rule: end 
nextState(1): end
rule: end
```

I really don't know whats wrong there. Could somebody help me please?

Comment: You probably have tailing whitespace. Try `if(states.get(i).getName().trim().equals(ruleSplitted.get(0).trim()))`

Comment: Other than that please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: It's not a bug. You might have empty characters. Use `trim()` and report back.

Comment: trim() is solvin this problem thank you

Comment: `rule: end ` there is a hanging space in this String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears either `states.get(i).getName()` or `ruleSplitted.get(0)` has a trailing white space. You can even see it in your copy paste of the console:

```
nextState(0): state1
rule: end 
nextState(1): end
rule: end 
         ^Right here
```

Use the [`String#trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) method to remove the trailing whitespace(s):

```
if(states.get(i).getName().trim().equals(ruleSplitted.get(0).trim()))
```